# How to handle the ajax response with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<script
 src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").on('click',function()
  {
  var email=$("#email").val();
  var pnumber=$("#pnumber").val();
   $.ajax(
  {
  url:'action.php',
  method:'post',
  data:{
  email:email,
   pnumber:pnumber
  },
  success:function(response)
  {
 $("#error").html(response);
 },
datatype:'text'
 }
);
 }
);
});
 </script>
```

I have created form that contains the phone number and email id .After clicking on the submit button the request goes to server and server will check whether the phone number is present in the database and email id is present in the database.
if the email id is present at the database it has to display message that email is already present and the same with the phone number.

so Iam using the jquery response in order to get the response from server.
so,how to validate that response in the jquery?
if the phone number error is the response, it should display the error message at the phone number column in the form page.

if the email error is the response ,it should display the error message at the email id  column in the form page .

iam using PHP at the server side.

iam actually asking how check that  that response is phone number error or email error in order to display the error message at a particular field in the form page.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $response = array();
    if($phn_number){
     $response['phn_number_exist'] = 'phone number exist';
    }else{
     $response['phn_number_error'] = 'phone number error';
    }

    if($email){
     $response['email_exist'] = 'email exist';
    }else{
     $response['email_error'] = 'email error';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

    //and in your script

    success: function(data){
     obj =JSON.parse(data);
    if(obj.phn_number_error){
     alert('phone number error');
    }
if(obj.email_error){
     alert('email error');
    }
    }
```